# How would we sterilize a probe to look for life?

Tags: probe, astrobiology, forward-contamination, sterilization, integration

If we were to ever send a probe to check for life then it's of paramount importance that we do not contaminate the target site with Earth organisms. And if there's anything we've learned from [extremophiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremophile) is that life is very persistent. How would we go about sterilizing a probe so that we would be sure without a shadow of doubt that no trace of life is clinging to it until it reaches its destination?